# Changing "Number Format" to "Numeric" in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes

I'm having some trouble creating a dot density map. When I use the dot density symbology, all the fields don't show up to choose from. I think this is because some of my fields don't have a number format.

How do I change "Number Format" to "Numeric" in my attribute table? The field that I'm trying to edit currently has the object type: "text" even though the content of the field is all numbers and under "number format" it is blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by changing the number format of the cells in Libre Office and then joining it to my shapefile. This allowed me to choose from more fields for the dot density symbology.